# get content when error on subscribe with angular2

Tags: angular

I am sending a post request with angular 2 and getting an error.
When there is an error, the server answers with an http error code and json data, however I have been unable to access the json data for some reason.

```
this.http.get(this.url).subscribe( (res: any) => {
 console.log(res);
}, e => {
 console.error(e.json());
}
```

Using the chrome's debugger I see the url answer is

```
{"errors": [{"field":"input", "errorMessage":"invalid content"}]}
```

However I cannot access that data on the client.
The logger prints

```
Blob {size: 65, type: "application/json"}
```

Am I missing on something?

Edit 1:
Rephrasing my question.
The server response is 400

The body is like this:

```
{"errores":[{"fieldName":"dictaminacion","errorMessage":"No es posible generar notificación file.doc pues no existen notificaciones por inconsistencia anteriores."}]}
```

However I have not been able to access it on the error handler of the request.
whe I do

```
e => console.log(e.json())
```

I literally get

```
Blob {size: 177, type: "application/json"}
```

(as in an object with a size attribute with value 177 and a type attribute with value "application/json")

Comment: try this: `this.http.get(this.url).map(res => res.json()).subscribe(console.log,console.log)` this has to print the response no matter what, Otherwise, I'd say it might be a bug. Also, can you post the HTTP response code?

Comment: I have no problem when the page returns no error code. I am trying to read json when I get an error code from the server. Hence the e => { ... } is what I am having problems with.

Comment: you probably have to use Rx `.catch` as described [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html#!#fetch-data-with-_http-get-_) see the `HeroService `

Comment: No luck with that either.